# How to get the joint distribution of multimodal deep Boltzmann machine?

Tags: probability-distributions

[image]

Here is the graph model of the multimodal dbm. I want to know how to inference the joint distribution of this probability graph model.
[image]

Some example equations are here. For the expression, I have two questions.

---

1. How to get the second line?
2. Why $p(v^m,h^{1m}|h^{2m})$ is a **Boltzmann distribution**?

---

It would be great if you could provide the whole process to get the final expression of $p(v^m,v^t)$.

---

The source of these photos are from http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14b/srivastava14b.pdf
and https://slideplayer.com/slide/13728662/

Comment: Thank you. The source of these photos are from http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14b/srivastava14b.pdf
and https://slideplayer.com/slide/13728662/

Comment: The second line follows from the structure of the graphical model (independence of the two sides of the model given $h^{2m}$, $h^{2t}$, and $h^3$). Beyond that, I do not understand what exactly you are asking.